# Why do I get IndexError: string index out of range in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
message_text = ["text1\n", variable1, "\ntext2", variable2, "\ntext3", variable3]
u = MIMEText(message_text[0][1][2][3][4][5])
u['Subject'] = 'title of email'
s.sendmail("test1@test.com", "example1@example.com", u.as_string())
```

I got the error on this line:

`u = MIMEText(message_text[0][1][2][3][4][5])`

The error:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What should I do?

When creating `u`, I loaded the indices `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` from `message_text`, but that created the error.

[Example Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHUEa.png)

Comment: Please include the traceback _as [formatted text](/help/formatting)_ instead of a screenshot

Comment: `message_text[0]` is `'text1\n'`, then `'text1\n'[1]` is `'e'`, and then `'e'[2]` doesn't exist because you are trying to access the 3rd character of the one-character string `e` - oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure how  the MIMEText function works, but I think it takes in a text string instead of a list of strings. You can try writing something like this instead and see if it works:

```
message_text = f"text1\n{variable1}\ntext2{variable2}\ntext3{variable3}" 
u = MIMEText(message_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a multi-dimensional array.
Here's what python sees.

Take `message_text[0]` which is `"text1\n"`

Now take `message_text[0][1]` which is `"e"`

Now with `message_text[0][1][2]` we try to find what is the third element in `"e"`
This doesn't make sense, because the string `"e"` only has one element: the character `'e'`.

If you want to add them all together, you'll need to convert your variables into text, and string them together.

```
u = MIMEText(message_text[0] + str(message_text[1]), message_text[2], str(message_text[3]), message_text[4], str(message_text[5]))
```

Converts all your variables into one long string before passing it the MIMEText command.